# Whenever I edit .ts file in angular2 ng serve is closed. Getting the below error message "ERROR in Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: channel closed"

Tags: angular

ERROR in Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: channel closed
    at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:590:16)
    at AngularCompilerPlugin._updateForkedTypeChecker (C:\wamp\www\component-binding\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_
compiler_plugin.js:370:34)
    at Promise.resolve.then (C:\wamp\www\component-binding\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:208:22)

```
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more details ? like node version, npm version, typescript version and which machine you are running your project etc ?

Comment: npm - 5.5.1 / TypeScript Version 2.6.1 / Node v8.8.0. I am running on Windows 7.